# node.js forever daemon, how to exit properly?

Tags: node.js, forever

When using forever to run a node.js program as a daemon 
i.e.

```
forever start myNodeTask
```

If the daemon (`myNodeTask`) decides it needs to exit, what is the correct way to do so?

If I just call `process.exit()` the program does terminate but it doesn't delete the forever log file, which leads me to believe that I need the program to exit in a more forever-friendly manner.

The node tasks I'm running are plain tcp servers that stream data to connected clients, not web servers.

Comment: I don't believe it removes logs when a process is stopped. To check if the process is still running, use `forever list`.

Comment: For ubuntu I do - 1.) `forever list` it will show you all running  forever processes with the pid. 2) `forever stop` <pid>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forever` module always keeps the log files, even after a process has finished. There is no *forever-friendly manner* to delete those files.

But, you could use the [`forever-monitor`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor) module, which allow you to programatically use `forever` (from the [docs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor#usage)):

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor'),
    fs      = require('fs');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('your-filename.js', {
  max: 3,
  silent: true,
  options: []
});

child.on('exit', function () {
  console.log('your-filename.js has exited after 3 restarts');
  // here you can delete your log file
  fs.unlink('path_to_your_log_file', function (err) {
    // do something amazing
  });
});

child.start();
```